# Android: Acces app from other app

Tags: android

I would like to acces my app from another app. For instance, i would like to, from the build-in SMS-application, to copy some text and add the text to my database. But the whole action should be done from the SMS-application. Is that possible?

Further explanation:
I am making a grocery-list app. My idea is then, that is someone text you: "Can you pick up potatoes?", then you can long click on the sms, pick the word "potato" and add it to the database in my app, directly from the SMS-application.

Regards
Jesper

Comment: yes it is possible using implicit intent

Comment: but please make the question more clear........

Comment: I have made a further explanation

Comment: "directly from the build-SMS-application" looks very difficult .... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each application in Android runs in it's own separate process, and it's isolated from other applications. But there is a way to interact and share information between applications, using Content Providers.
Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

You will find out how you can access other's application database, and get information from there (for your application, the messages stored in the sms application database).

Comment: So is it possible to make a shortcut in the SMS-application, so i could for instance long-click on a message and then, among the build-in things, i could choose an action like adding it to my database?

Comment: The [context menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#FloatingContextMenu), what you are describing as long-click, is described by the application that is open. You can't change the options that are provided there unless you make your own SMS application. On the other hand, you could attempt to catch an Intent coming off of one of those options.

Comment: You can pop up a dialog with information from sms database, and then by selecting something from that dialog, you can add it to your database, but manually by inserting it

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the same which has been suggested by 'Arkde'.

probably you want to look for Content provider tutorial to do this. You can find one [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)
But before going to this tutorial read the documentation provided by Android.
If you want to use context menu in your application then read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html). This will make your application more interactive.